# Does django-constance admin supports database backend?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I'm trying to setup the admin to show settings meant to be stored in database backend (Postgres 9.5.0).  I manually created values in shell_plus as follows:

In [1]: from constance.backends.database.models import Constance

In [2]: first_record = Constance.objects.get(id=1)

In [3]: first_record
Out[3]:

pg-admin properly shows the entry although django admin doesn't show it at all. I ran migrate command for both databases (I have default and product databases) but the record still is not showing up. Certainly I can make it work with forcing to register with admin as follows:
admin.site.register(Constance)
but my question is if it's necessary?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, they do.

You need to manage dependencies, but you can just use next command to install:

```
pip install "django-constance[database]"
```

Also you need to add some additionl settings to your `settings.py` :

```
CONSTANCE_BACKEND = 'constance.backends.database.DatabaseBackend'

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    # other apps
    'constance.backends.database',
)

#optional - in case you want specify table prefix

CONSTANCE_DATABASE_PREFIX = 'constance:myproject:'
```

Then you need to apply migrations by running command `python manage.py migrate database`

For displaying settings inputs in admin you should specify them in your `settings.py`. There are various types of fields and you even can add your own types of fields using `CONSTANCE_ADDITIONAL_FIELDS` parameter.

```
CONSTANCE_CONFIG = {
    'THE_ANSWER': (42, 'Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, '
                       'The Universe, and Everything'),
}
```

You can read more at documentation [page](http://django-constance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: All the settings were made and pip installation was done as suggested

Comment: @ReginaSas  updated answer with additional info. For displaying them in admin area you should define inputs in `setting.py`

Comment: This is exactly the reason for me trying to move some settings from settings.py and store them in database unless I misinterpret this library purpose.

Comment: @ReginaSas as I can see in https://github.com/jazzband/django-constance/blob/master/constance/admin.py  they take input fields from `settings.CONFIG.items()` which is actually `CONFIG = getattr(settings, 'CONSTANCE_CONFIG', {})` .

So there is no possibility to add inputs in different way.

As I can understand, you do not want to store some settings in `setting.py` ?

`django-constance` allows you only to add possibility for users to change sime settings in admin area, but not to create new name-values.

Comment: yes, it's correct that I prefer not to store some settings in settings.py. And it looks like you're right about CONFIG = getattr(settings, 'CONSTANCE_CONFIG', {}). I'm still unsure though what developers mean when they say that it supports database backend then.

Comment: @ReginaSas I think they main goal was to allow admin edit some settings parameters from web interface, without actually change source files.

I `settings.py` you only set up default value, but it could be overrided from admin.

Comment: Thanks for your response.